# Entity Framework Core 6 logs all queries as warnings

Tags: linq, logging, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Whenever I'm calling my context through EF Core 6, I'm getting the resulting query outputted as a warning in my logs.

I'm calling the context through LINQ like this:

```
var result = await _context.Table.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The warning I'm getting in the logs looks like this (with the individual columns instead of the *):

```
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__deviceId_0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM [Table] AS [o]
```

I've made sure that all of the columns that can contain a null value are noted as such in the dataobject.

What can I have overlooked? I can't figure out what could result in these warnings.

Comment: Have you configured warnings in your EF context? Perhaps in DI setup?

Comment: @DavidG nope. It's simple services.AddDbContext<context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionstring)) and then services.AddScoped<IRepo, Repo>

Comment: Nothing in the DbContext itself?

Comment: Logging configuration?

Comment: @DavidG you were right. It was in the context itself: 

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(c => c.Log((RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting, LogLevel.Warning)));
        }

Comment: I guess you were right too @ErikEJ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out a colleague had configured logging for CommandExecuting as warnings in the context itself

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(c => c.Log((RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting, LogLevel.Warning)));
    }
```